# Call a textfield from other view controller in swift (prepareforsegue)

Tags: swift, function, segue

I read a lot of posts and videos of this and I read that is with a function calls "prepareforsegue" but I don´t understand where to implement and what other things do I have to do. I have 4 textfields that I want to call from another later controller. Thank you very much for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set values or access to textfields or any other outlet inside `prepareforsegue` method. That because `prepareforsegue` method is called "before" the destination controller's outlets get set. So you need to create a variable in your destination controller that receives the value for the textfield and then in `viewDidLoad` in destination controller set it to the textfield.

In prepareforsegue method :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
        destinationViewController.valueForTextField = "Hi"
    }
}
```

In the destination controller (which is SecondViewController in my case) :

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
var valueForTextField: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.text = valueForTextField
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to post your code.

Inside `prepareForSegue`, grab the destination ViewController that holds your textFields by using:

`let vc = segue.destinationViewController`

then `vc.textField1.text = "Your Text here"` & repeat for your other text fields.